# How can I copy combobox contents programmatically?

Tags: c#, dynamic, combobox

I've got this code:

```
private void FormMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmbx;
    foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
    {
        if (C.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
        {
            cmbx = C as ComboBox;
            //cmbx.Items.AddRange(cmbxRow0Element0.Items); <= illegal
            object[] obj = new object[cmbxRow0Element0.Items.Count];
            cmbxRow0Element0.Items.CopyTo(obj, 0);
            cmbx.Items.AddRange(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

...but it doesn't work - I have several combo boxes on a tabPage on a tabControl on a Form, with cmbxRow0Element0 populated with items at design time. The above attempt to copy its items to all the other comboboxes fails, though.

### UPDATE

This is the code I now have, and it still doesn't work:

```
public FormMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        this.cmbxRow0Element0.Items.Add(String.Format("Item {0}", i.ToString()));
    }
    foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
    {
        ComboBox cmbx = null;

        // The & test ensures we're not just finding the source combobox
        if ((C.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox)) & ((C as ComboBox) != this.cmbxRow0Element0))
            cmbx = C as ComboBox;
        if (cmbx != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in cmbxRow0Element0.Items)
            {
                cmbx.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Perhaps it's something to do with the comboboxes being on tab pages on the tab control?

### UPDATE 2

A breakpoint on the first line below is reached, but the second line is never reached:

```
if ((C.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox)) & ((C as ComboBox) != this.cmbxRow0Element0))
   cmbx = C as ComboBox;
```

### UPDATE 3

The problem was the "find" was not being specific enough - the particular tabPage has to be specified. For more details, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835568/why-do-items-from-one-combobox-not-copy-to-another/23835953).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var items = cmbxRow0Element0.Items.OfType<object>().ToArray();

foreach (ComboBox c in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
     c.Items.AddRange(items);
}
```

If you are using `tabControl` as a container, then it means your comboboxes aren't direct child element of your Form.So you need to access `Control` collection of the container which is the `tabControl`. You can do that using `this.NameOfYourTabControl.Controls`.

Comment: The other combo boxes are not populated with the values from cmbxRow0Element0.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon instead of this.Controls. can you try using : `this.NameOfYourTABControl.Controls`?

Comment: That also fails (foreach (ComboBox c in this.tabControl1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()))

Answer (score 1):

A quick test Windows Form app (VS Express 2012) shows this works. In a new blank Windows Form app, drop three (or more) ComboBox controls:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("Item {0}", i.ToString()));
        }
        foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
        {
            ComboBox cmbx = null;

            // The & test ensures we're not just finding the source combobox
            if ((C.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox)) & ((C as ComboBox) != this.comboBox1))
                cmbx = C as ComboBox;
            if (cmbx != null)
            {
                foreach (Object item in comboBox1.Items)
                {
                    cmbx.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to have to specify each subsequent combobox by name (as "comboBox2" above; there will be dozens of them.

Comment: I don't see any reason you'd have to; if you have a reference to any combobox, you can use that as either the source or destination for the copy using the code here (which is what your question asks). IOW, `cmbx = C as ComboBox; foreach (Object item in srcCombo.Items) { cmbx.Items.Add(item); }` works fine.

Comment: I'm editing to add a (rather meaningless) example of how you can use it without knowing the name of the destination ComboBox first, just to show it can be done with the logic above. :-)

Comment: This does not work, either; it appends "Item 0" ... "Item 9" to the original combobox, but does not populate the others.

Comment: Then you're not using the code I posted. I tested it thoroughly, with a new blank Windows Form and three ComboBox controls (as the text says), and each list ended up with a single copy of the numbered list. Would you like me to attach an image to show it? The `& ((C as ComboBox) != this.comboBox1))` specifically eliminates the source combo from being included.